# How to remove chinese values stored in varchar2

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a few Chinese values stored in `varchar2` data type oracle10g xe , could some one please help me by guiding me how to remove these. I wrote a `plsql` script but on saving and opening the `.sql` file in `sql plus`, I see `???` in place of Chinese the characters which I picked from the db for replacement.

I did some research myself to find out the character set being used in my db 
`SELECT value$ FROM sys.props$ WHERE name = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET' ;`. It gave me
`AL32UTF8`

I am not sure how to remove this Chinese data from the db, which got inserted by mistake. Help appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to remove the whole record or just these characters?

Comment: Hi A.B.Cade, I want to replace these characters with constant value.. Essentially i want to clean this data up.. Any solutions/suggestions?

Comment: You can try `REGEXP_REPLACE` i.e. `regexp_replace(your_col, '[^A-Za-z0-9 !@#$%^&*()_+-=]', 'CONSTANT')` which means- replace whatever is not in the list of characters in brackets

Comment: Thanks A.B.. will try and let you know..